# Join a table more than one time and not to get duplicated rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have this query on querybuilder and I want to make it return unique rows. This is the structure:

table 1 : store

table 2 service

table 3 : relation_store_service

The case is the following:

table 3 `relation_store_service` has 3 id fields: `family_id`, `category_id` and `subcategory_id` and they references to the same table and same id field. `i want to join the ids on store and service id to their tables.

My query is the following (spanish code, so aware, i explained it above). The problem is that I'm getting the registers in table 3 times, one for every join.

```
SELECT rssp.sucursa_serviciol_id,
       rssp.servicio_id,
       rssp.sucursal_id,
       s.clave_interna,
       s.nombre,
       cscs.nombre as nombre_categoria,
       cscs2.nombre as nombre_subcategoria,
       cscs3.nombre as nombre_familia
FROM rel_sucursales_servicios_paquetes AS rssp
JOIN servicios AS s 
    ON rssp.servicio_id = s.servicio_id
JOIN cat_servicios_categorias_subcategorias_familias cscs 
    ON cscs.categoria_familia_id = s.categoria_id 
JOIN cat_servicios_categorias_subcategorias_familias cscs2 
    ON cscs2.categoria_familia_id = s.subcategoria_id 
JOIN cat_servicios_categorias_subcategorias_familias cscs3 
    ON cscs3.categoria_familia_id = s.familia_id
```

Comment: MySql is not PostgreSQL yet you've tagged both.

Answer (score 0):

another option is to use case statements in a nested query.  I made an attempt using your tables, but I can't be sure without seeing the table structure.  I hope this helps!

```
    select
        *
     from
     (select
          rssp.sucursa_servicio_id,
          rssp.servicio_id, 
          rssp.sucursal_id,
          s.clave_interna,
          s.nombre,
          t1.nombre_categoria,
          t1.nombre_subcategoria,
          t1.nombre_familia
          case
             when categoria_familia_id = XXX then categoria_familia_id
          end nombre_categoria,
          case 
             when subcategoria_id = YYY then categoria_familia_id
          end nombre_subcategoria,
          case 
             when familia_id = ZZZ then categoria_familia_id
          end nombre_familia
   from rel_sucursales_servicios_paquetes AS rssp
   JOIN servicios AS s ON rssp.servicio_id = s.servicio_id
   join cat_servicios_categorias_subcategorias_familias cscs ON -- add a join here) t1
```